# Selenium Chromedriver on remote Mac machine very slow and timing out

Tags: selenium, bamboo, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a Selenium test suite on multiple browsers on a remote Apple Mini. I schedule these tests with Bamboo.

When running the tests on Chrome, they are extremely slow and some actions timeout, causing the tests to fail.

More interestingly, this only happens when Bamboo kicks off the test. When I kick off the tests from my local computer, they run fine.

I have read that Chromedriver performs poorly sometimes when automatically detecting proxy settings. I have addressed this but still the performance is poor.

Has something like this happened to others and does anyone know what could cause something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happens to me.

The root cause can be in the network connection between the Bamboo server (where the project is built) and the Selenium server (which probably runs on another machine).

When you kick off tests suite from your local machine, you probably have the project build and Selenium running at the same place. So, the commands sent to Selenium do not have to pass the network stage and there are almost no delays.

Try to eliminate the slow connection or investigate if it is possible to build and launch your tests on the machine which runs the Selenium server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this when running tests on Team City with multiple browsers on a remote Mac Mini.

After much head scratching we stumble upon the fact that tests sped up if we remotely connected or connected a monitor to the Mac Mini.

We can only assume that the Mac Mini is smart enough to reduce resource to GUI activities if it knows there is no mechanism to attach a GUI.

Therefore, we purchased a very cheap monitor and left it attached to the MAc Mini, and all started running normally